# how to simulate click on button with javafx

Tags: java, button, javafx

I have two `Button`s ; `toRed` and `toGreen` . When `toRed` is clicked it switches the `Scene` to the `Scene` "Green" and a `Timer`(using thread) is started. It counts down from 5 to 0  and then switches back to `Scene` Red . In my `Timer` class I implemented this so:

```
public void run() {

    try{
        while(running){
            if (seconds==1 && goBack){

                this.seconds = 6;
                running=false;
                toRed.fire();

            }   ......
```

but `toRed.fire()` seems not to work (nothing changes) . How can I simulate a click on the `Button` in my `Timer` class, which is in my Main class?

Comment: Instead of adding an Event Handler to your buttons add the name of a function that does what you want your button to do so in your timer you call the function instead of firing a button

Comment: That's true, but "toRed.fire();" should work. Are you sure that execution reaches this line?

Comment: Yes , I'm sure . I also tried with toRed.arm();

Comment: Then post more code, especially where you register the handler and where you changing scenes.

Comment: Try executing `fire` from the javafx application thread: `Platform.runLater(toRed::fire);`

Comment: @fabian Thanks a lot , this works !

Comment: This works for me aswell, but it doesn't look like the button is clicked in the actual GUI. I have specific style in my css for when my button is clicked, but this isn't shown when I call fire(my code for the button is executed however).